# Баг с AVPlayer при повторном открытии приложения

Tags: swift

Воспроизвожу аудио-файлы через `AVPlayer`
Проблема заключается в том что когда я прослушаю какой либо аудио-файл, затем выйду из приложения и зайду обратно, то этот аудио-файл проиграется снова, как будто я нажал на кнопку проигрывания, хотя я этого не делал
Тоже самое происходит если заблокировать устройство, а затем разблокировать.
Юзаю такой код

```
let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableview)
    let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRow(at:buttonPosition)
    let cell = self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! WordsTableViewCell
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: cell.ru_audio_url.text ?? ""))
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.play()
```